# Finding connection between data

Tags: python

Suppose I have a set of points `X=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)`, each point `x_i=(a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i, e_i, f_i, g_i, h_i)`.

There should be some fixed connection between values on different axis of `x_i`.

**For example**

The connection could be `a_i*h_i=d_i*e_i=b_i*g_i=c_i*f_i` but this relationship is unknown a priori. Is there a Python module for finding this kind of relationship between data ? `x_i` comes from a very accurate measurement but might not be exactly accurate and the number of measurements 'n' can be as large as I want.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and guess that no, there's probably not a general module that can simply figure out the (potentially non-existent) mathematical relationship between a bunch of arbitrary values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use module [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) and [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

These two modules are usually used for data analysis and processing.